# Why is my lamda null when sorting a list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, blazor

I have a class called Books, I am creating a list and populating it as follows

```
List<Books> booklist = new List<Books>();

foreach (BooksUsers bu in userbooks)
{
    Books book = _context.Books.Where(b => b.BookId == bu.BookId).Where(b => b.Void == false).FirstOrDefault();
    booklist.Add(book);
}
```

I want to sort the list by BookTitle, and am getting null reference exceptions on the lambda

I tired this

```
booklist.Sort((x, y) => x.BookTitle.CompareTo(y.BookTitle));
```

But get this

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. x was null.

I tried this

```
List<Books> SortedList = booklist.OrderBy(o => o.BookTitle).ToList();
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. o was null.

and this

```
booklist.OrderBy(bl => bl.BookTitle).ToList();
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. bl was null.

booklist has items.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Clearly something that list is null. You will have to debug your code to figure out what it is.

Comment: One of your books is null.

Comment: Yes, it is, thank you

Comment: if (book != null)
                    {
                        booklist.Add(book);
                    }